# How to change the file name before store in file and database

Tags: c#, file

this code is to check does the user has upload any file and the file namd.

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile) {
    fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;
    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Data/") + fileName);
    fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/Data/") + fileName;
}
```

I wonder can I add the current date on the end of the file name. my file can be any type of file. I do try add on FileName= FileUpload1.FileName+updateon; but the file will save as example.jpg11062015 and the file will be corrupted.

anyone has any idea how to do it?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Path` to separate `FileName` into a file name and an extension, insert the date in the middle, and combine them back, like this:

```
var fn = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
var ext = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
var fileName = string.Format("{0}{1:yyyy-MM-dd}.{2}", fn, DateTime.Now, ext);
```

Comment: there is no path key word in my compiler.. I am using visual studio C# asp.net

Comment: @LstPatrick Add `using  System.IO;` at the top. Here is the class reference: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @LstPatrick There's something else going on then. Extension gets preserved, right? Do you get the same size of upload?

Answer (score 1):

Try parsing the file name into parts, and inserting your date in between, like this:

```
var newFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileUpload1.FileName)
                  + "11062015"  // or wherever the date is coming from
                  + Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
```

> Original file name: "someFile.ext"
>
> Modified file name: "someFile11062015.ext"

Comment: there is no path key word in my compiler.. I am using visual studio C# asp.net